Which is larger? 999,999! or 2^(11!)
Without using a calculator or computer, please show steps in order
to determine
which expression is larger.
$999{,}999!$ versus $2^{11!}$

stirling formula might help

@OliveStemforn : in Julia : BigInt(2)^(factorial(11)) > factorial(BigInt(999999)) returns true so using computers would have helped indeed.

Tiny LaTeX improvement (too small for a suggested edit): wrap the comma in $999{,}999$ in curly braces to prevent the whitespace after it.

@ Ben Reiniger -- Thank you.  I did that.  I want to remember that for other problems/posts.


 $2^{11!}$ is bigger.

Explanation:

 Let's assume $2^4 = 10$ for the sake of this explanation (it doesn't, but it only undervalues $2^{11!}$.) I know 11! is roughly 40,000,000, but a bit smaller, so to err on the side of caution let's call it 30,000,000. We can now write $2^{11!}$ as $(2^4)^{7500000}$, or (since we let $2^4 = 10$), $10^{7500000}$.

Let's now go to the other side.

 We know that $999999!$ is less than $1000000!$ (obviously.) We also know that $1000000!$ is less than $1000000^{1000000}$, since $1000000!$ is a product of one million numbers that are less than or equal to 1000000, and $1000000^{1000000}$ is the product of one million numbers that are one million. We can rewrite $1000000^{1000000}$ as $(10^6)^{1000000}$, or $10^{6000000}$.

Now we can see that

 $10^{6000000}$ (which is much LARGER than 999999!) is less than $10^{7500000}$ (which is much SMALLER than $2^{11!}$, since we let $2^4 = 10$.)

so we know that

 $2^{11!}$ is bigger.

Edit: The real values are roughly:

 $8*10^{5565702}$ for $999999!$ and $10^{12016154}$ for $2^{11!}$.


to make it closer you can use 2¹⁰ = 1000

@phuclv That's true; I could also have just kept it as 16- it doesn't really matter. My brain was just stuck on Fermi estimation, to be honest.

You skip some steps, such as when you just declare "I know 11! is roughly 40,000,000, but a bit smaller". Did you do that in your head?

@Acccumulation I happen to have 11! memorized, which is why I didn't go into it that much in the solution, but it's not too hard to get above 30,000,000 with similar underestimation techniques; e. g. rounding down 7! to 5,000 (7! is easily doable by hand or mentally), then *8 = 40,000, *9 = 360,000, *10 = 3,600,000, and then *11 is very clearly over 30,000,000.

All  the exclamation  marks make me feel like I'm being yelled at. +1


$$\begin{align}&999{,}999!\\<&(1{,}000{,}000)^{1{,}000{,}000}\\=&(1000\cdot1000)^{1,000,000}\\<&(1024\cdot1024)^{1,000,000}\\=&(2^{10}\cdot2^{10})^{1,000,000}\\=&2^{20,000,000}\\<&2^{21,600,000}\\=&2^{720\times300\times100}\\<&2^{6!\times(7\cdot8\cdot9)\times(10\cdot11)}\\=&2^{11!}\end{align}$$


I also accept this as good/thorough answer, but I can't make it a green check mark, too.

No worries. To be fair the accepted answer was earlier than mine by 1 minute.

@BenjaminWang FWIW, I think your answer is definitely cleaner than mine, lol.

I love it.  Not to detract but if we're going really small step by step, perhaps before line 2: <1,000,000^1,000,000, then make line 3 =?

What about 1,111,111!?

I used a straightforward approach of a professional mathematician,
which boiled down to simple arithmetic estimations.

 By Stirling formula, for each natural $n$ there exists a number $0<\theta<1$ such that $$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot\left(\frac ne\right)^n e^{\frac \theta{12n}}.$$


 So $$999999!<10^6!<\sqrt{2\pi\cdot 10^6}\cdot \left(\frac {10^6}e\right)^{10^6}\cdot 2<2^{12}\cdot \left(2^{19}\right)^{10^6}\cdot 2$$ and $$11!>\sqrt{22\pi}\cdot \left(\frac {11}e\right)^{11}>8\cdot 4^{11}=2^{25}>32\cdot 10^6>19\cdot 10^6+13,$$ so $$999999!<2^{11!}.$$


"I used a straightforward approach of a professional mathematician, which boiled down to simple arithmetic estimations."  I appreciate your sense of humour, whether intentional or not.

I clicked a "like" on your solution.

This does require the reader to connect a small amount of dots that $2^{12} \cdot (2^{19})^{10^6} \cdot 2= 2^{19 \cdot 10^6+13}$ and so since the log base 2 of that is less than $11!$,  it follows that it is less than $2^{11!}$


$11!=39,916,800>20,000,000=20\times1,000,000$


$\therefore2^{11!}>2^{20\times1,000,000}$


$=1,048,576^{1,000,000}$


$n!$ has $n$ factors, each of which is $\leq n$. For the first figure, $n=999,999$. In the manipulated form above, $2^{11!}$ has $10^6$ factors, each of which is larger than $10^6$. Hence, the latter is larger.


I also accept this as good/thorough answer, but I can't make it a green check mark, too.

Using the estimate $\ln x!\approx x\ln x$ makes this fairly straightforward to estimate to better precision than is needed to determine which is bigger. After playing around a little with bases of logs, I found it was easiest with paper and pencil to estimate the log base 10 of the natural log of each number.
For the first number, $\log\ln (999999!)\approx 6+\log(6\ln 10)\approx 7$.
Using the same method for the second number, $\log\ln 2^{11!}\approx 11\ln 11/\ln 10+\log 2\approx 11$. So the second one is clearly bigger.

I don't see how you would know that the ln(x!) approximation would be good enough at x = 999,999.  For instance, at x = 69 (a common limit before an overflow when taking factorials on scientific calculators), ln(69!) ~ 226 and 69*ln(69) ~ 292. The 292 represents about a 29% error too much compared to 226.

The approximation $\ln x!\approx x\ln x$ is linearly loose. Stirling's formula provides much more precise
approximation $$\ln x!=x\ln x-x+\frac {\ln x}2+\frac {\ln 2\pi}{2}+\frac{\theta}{12x},$$ for some $\theta\in (0,1)$.

This was my first thought as well. It's simple enough that you can easily solve this in your head, if you're comfortable with logs

Note for later:  $ \ \ 999,999 \  < 1,000,000 \ < \ 1,048,576 \  =  \ 2^{20}$
$999,999! \ \ \ vs. \ \ \ 2^{11!}$
$log_2(999,999!) \ \ \ vs. \ \ \ log_2(2^{11!})$
$[< log_2(1,000,000!)] \  \ \ vs. \ \ \ 11! $
$[< log_2(1,000,000) \ + \ log_2(999,999) \ + \ ... \ + log_2(1)] \ \ \ vs. \ \ \ 11! $
$[< 1,000,000*log_2(2^{20})] \ \ \ vs. \ \ \ 11! $
$(< 1,000,000*20) \ \ \ vs. \ \ \ 11!$
$(<20,000,000) \ \ \ vs. \ \ \ 11!$
$(<20,000,000) \ \ \ vs.  \ \ \ 7!*(8*9)*(10*11)$
$(<20,000,000) \ \ \ vs. \ \ \ (> 5,000*70*100)$
$(<20,000,000) \ \ \   < \ \ \ (> 35, 000,000)$
Therefore, $ \ \ 2^{11!} \ $ is larger than $ \ 999,999!$


 Take the logarithm base 2 of both. 
$\log_2 2^{11!} = 11! = 33,916,800$ (this can be worked out by hand)
$\log_2 (999,999!) = \sum_{i=1}^{999,999} \log_2 i < 999,999 \log_2 999,999$
$< 1,000,000 \cdot 20 = 20,000,000 < 33,916,800$


Which one is larger?

 The latter.

Why?

 $999,999! = 1 \times 2 \times ... \times 999,999 = 2 \times ... \times 999,999$ $999,999 = 10^6-1$ $999,999! > 10^{3 \times 999,998}$  $1024 \times 1024> 999,999 > 1024 \times 512$  $2^{20} >999,999 > 2^{19}$ $2^{11!} = 2 \times 2... \times 2$ ($11!$ times)  $999,999 = 10^6-1$  $11! = 2^{5+2+1}\times 3^{3+1} \times 5^2 \times 7\times11 =  2^8\times 3^4 \times 5^2 \times 7\times11$ $3^3>5^2$  $11>5\times2$ $3^1 \times 2\times7 > 5^2$  $3^4 \times 7\times11 > 5^5$  $3^4 \times 7\times11 \times 5^2> 5^7$  $11! = 2^8\times 3^4 \times 5^2 \times 7\times11 > 2\times10^7$ $999,998! < (2^{20}/2)^{999,998}$ $999,998! < 2^{19 \times 999,998}$  $999,999! < 2^{19 \times 999,998 +20}$, so $999,999! < 2^{2 \times 10^7}$


$$n!\approx \sqrt {2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$
$$\frac{2^{11!}}{999,999!}>\frac{2^{11!}}{10^6!}\approx\frac{2^{11!}}{\sqrt{2*10^6*\pi} \left(\frac{10^6}{e}\right)^{{10}^6}}>\frac{2^{11!}}{\sqrt{2*10^6*\pi} \left(500,000\right)^{{10}^6}}>\frac{2^{11!}}{10^{6*10^{10}}}$$
$$=2^{11!-\log_2(10)*6*10^6}>2^{11!-24*10^6}>1$$
because
$$\frac{11!}{24*10^6}= \frac{11*9*8*7*3}{10^4}=\frac{16,632}{10,000}>1$$

If you used a calculator or computer, then it is not a method I was looking for.

@OliveStemforn the only calculation is  11∗9∗8∗7∗3 which is doable by hand

Hi. To compare approximate numbers we also need to estimate the approximation error. The rigorous application of Stirling's formula (even for both factorials) can be seen in my answer.
